# $f'(0)<0, f''(x)<0$ then for $\alpha\in(0,1)$, $f(x)\le f(0) + \alpha x f'(0)$ for all $x>0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f\in C^2, f'(0)<0, f''(x)<0$ for all
>   $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $\alpha\in(0,1)$. Prove that, for all $x>0$,
>   $$f(x)\le f(0) + \alpha x f'(0).$$

This is what I came up with:

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = f'(c),\  c\in (0,x)\implies\\f(x) = f(0) + xf'(c)$$

using the same argument for $f'(x):$

$$\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x-0} = f''(c_2), \ c_2\in(0,x)\implies f'(x) = f'(0) + xf''(c_2)$$

for $x=c$ we have $f'(c) = f'(0) + cf''(c_2)$ for $c_2\in(0,c)$

So

$$f(x) = f(0) + xf'(c) = f(0) + x(f'(0) + cf''(c_2)) \implies \\f(x) = f(0) + xf'(0) + xcf''(c_2)\le f(0)+\alpha f'(0)x + f''(c_2)cx\le f(0) + \alpha x f'(0)$$

for $\alpha\in (0,1)$

Comment: The graph of a decreasing and concave function lies below the tangent line at the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine. This is another one (with strict inequality). Since $f''(x)<0$ it follows that $f'$ is strictly decreasing and therefore, for $x>0$,
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = f'(c)<f'(0)\implies f(x)< f(0) + xf'(0)< f(0) + \alpha xf'(0)$$
for any $\alpha\in(0,1)$ where in the last step we used the fact that $f'(0)<0$.